Is there a way to foward a domain only if the request doesn't come from that domain
I have an odd question.  I have a client (company A) who is being absorbed into a larger company (company B).  The new company would like it so that anyone who goes to domainA gets forwarded to a certain page on newdomainb where there will be an explanation of the buyout. On that new page there would be a link to take the user back to domain A where they can continue looking through the original site.
The problem (to me) is that if I put a redirect from domainA to domainB to read that note, and then re-direct back to domainA that would be a very cyclical process getting the "too many redirects" error.
I asked the clients if we could just put a modal on domainA letting them know of the buyout, but they don't want to do that.
Is there a way to add a cookie or session note on my site so that if they have a cookie or something it doesn't do the redirect?  Or maybe a clever htaccess trick?
My site is in WordPress and I don't have full access to CompanyB's site but could likely get some code placed if that helps the solution.

There are a lot of ways to do this, so I'll provide the most simple solution, but you will have to implement it via whatever web stack you got.
What you should do is not implement a domain redirect. You should instead make the acquired website use a single cookie. If the cookie is not set, then redirect to the parent website's "we acquired them" page. That page could have a link that points back.
The acquired home page should set the cookie before loading the parent's "we acquired them" page.
That way when the user clicks thru from the parent site back to the original site, they won't be sent back.
